# Use bat script to add trusted site for IE

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-registry, internet-explorer-8

I just wrote a bat script file which add trusted site for ie.
In my bat script, I add a entry to this location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains
```

it does't work, but I can see my site was added in the ie security option panel.

and I also  note that, when you add trusted site in ie, a registry entry will be added to :

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1954385965-2893531047-659543403-1001\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Stats\{1DABF8D5-8430-4985-9B7F-A30E53D709B3}\iexplore\AllowedDomains
```

I don't know why, any one know the right way to add trusted site using bat script ?
here is my code:

```
@Echo off&title gworks
set "a=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\"
set b=192.168.1.100
reg add "%a%%b%" /v http /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f >nul 2>nul
reg add "%a%%b%" /v https /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f >nul 2>nul
```

after I execute it as administrator:
[image]

Comment: What version of Windows and IE?

Comment: @CharlieRB I run it on windows 7 with IE 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a TechNet posting which might help you.

**DISCLAIMER:** *Use at your own risk. It is advisable to make backups before proceeding.*

[Adding trusted Sites for all users](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/84d9ca9d-4a34-4294-ac90-8bc5c47edc12/adding-trusted-sites-for-all-users?forum=ieitpropriorver)

The answer marked as correct states:

> Try to add  these four keys.
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\mytest.org]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\mytest.org\pacs] "https"=dword:00000002
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains\mytest.org]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains\mytest.org\pacs] "https"=dword:00000002

Comment: This does not seem to work with Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: That's because this answer is for Windows 7.